# Check if the sum of two unsigned ints is larger than uint_max

Tags: c++, integer, unsigned-integer

Suppose I have two integers `x` and `y`, and I want to check whether their sum is larger than `UINT_MAX`.

```
#define UINT64T_MAX std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()

uint64_t x = foo();
uint64_t y = foo();
bool carry = UINT64T_MAX - x < y;
```

That code will work, but I want to know if there's a more efficient way to do it - possibly using some little-known feature that CPUs have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect integer overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-to-detect-integer-overflow)

Comment: Are there any constraints on the numerical values? Min/Max? Anything? (If so you could possibly knock it down to 1 comparison) In the general case one subtraction isn't bad, maybe you could use bit masks to determine if the two numbers ANDED together would create UINT64T_MAX, bitwise operations are pretty cheap but I don't know of AND would correctly account for overflow.

Comment: The title says `unsigned int`s and `uint_max` but the code says `uint64_t`. Which exactly did you mean?

Comment: If there's a "little-known CPU feature" then your compiler ought to know about it

Comment: @M.M that's true, but compilers aren't magic - you do need to "not prevent" them from applying any given optimization.  See "as if" rule.

Answer (score 9):

In C++, unsigned integer overflow has well-defined behavior. If you add two unsigned integers and the result is smaller than either one, then the calculation overflowed. (The result will always be smaller than both, so it doesn't matter which one you check.)

```
#define UINT64T_MAX std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()

uint64_t x = foo();
uint64_t y = foo();
uint64_t z = x + y;
bool carry = z < x;
```

I'm confident that this is the best way to do it in portable, well-defined C++. Clang and GCC both compile this trivial example to the optimal sequence of two amd64 instructions (`add x, y; setc carry`).

This does **not** generalize to signed integer overflow, as signed integer overflow is undefined behavior (although [some C++ committee members are looking to change that](https://twitter.com/jfbastien/status/964206601065324545)).

Some compilers offer [non-standard ways to check for overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20956705/251153) after various arithmetic functions, not just for addition, and not just for signed numbers. Using them for that added functionality might be worth investigating if you can afford to lose portability. For the specific case of unsigned addition overflow, performance is likely to be identical or negligibly faster in some non-trivial cases and it is probably not worth losing portability.

Comment: Is what I had, but the OP wants to check if it's bounded by INT_MAX; i.e. about half UINT_MAX.

Comment: What OP says in English is different from what OP says in code.

Comment: Actually I did mean UINT_MAX.

Comment: Not the first time a spec hasn't matched the code ;-)

Comment: when gcc sees your x+y<x, it automatically turns it (internally) into a call to those specialized builtins, so it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: The check should be `z < x || z > UINT_MAX` in light of the confirmed stipulation

Comment: @M.M, I think that this is another typo: OP edited his post in answer to the comment to change `INT_MAX` to `UINT_MAX` in the English text and left the code untouched, and that leads me to believe that the code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
auto t = x + y;
bool x_y_overflows_unsigned = t < x || t < y; // Actually, the second check is unnecessary.
```

would be hard to beat and is possibly clearer insofar that using subtraction with unsigned types often introduces bugs.

But if you are in any doubt, check the generated assembly.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: So they did, about to upvote that answer.